# Using foreach to loop more than two list<string>

Tags: c#

I'm trying to loop five list by merging them.

I know that this works fine

```
var zipped = letters.Zip(numbers, Tuple.Create);

 foreach (var tuple in zipped)
 {
     Console.WriteLine(tuple.Item1);
     Console.WriteLine(tuple.Item2);
 }
```

but i'm wondering I can use that same method, but with more list included.

Let's say I have the list `numbers`, `letters`, `words`, `pictures` and `songs`

How whould that loop look like then?

Comment: What is wrong with a for loop?

Comment: Have a function to "dump out the list" and send it a combined list of all the lists you want but you would of course need to have similar members in each

Comment: You can usually use the AddRange() method.  You can replace the foreach loop with a linq Select() method.

Comment: Please don't come with an entirely new question. If you have another question, please ask a new question instead of editing your existing one. Your question becomes a moving target.

Comment: @PatrickHofman It was exactly the same question with added example... Why did you remove it???

Comment: As I said, you are changing your question significantly. This is not a discussion forum where you can change your question over and over again.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest approach would probably be to reimplement `Zip` yourself multiple times, e.g.

```
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<T1, T2>> ZipTuple<T1, T2>(
    this IEnumerable<T1> source1,
    IEnumerable<T2> source2)

public static IEnumerable<Tuple<T1, T2, T3>> ZipTuple<T1, T2, T3>(
    this IEnumerable<T1> source1,
    IEnumerable<T2> source2,
    IEnumerable<T3> source3)

public static IEnumerable<Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4>> ZipTuple<T1, T2, T3, T4>(
    this IEnumerable<T1> source1,
    IEnumerable<T2> source2,
    IEnumerable<T3> source3,
    IEnumerable<T3> source4)
```

The implementation will be tedious, but it's [fairly simple to do](https://github.com/jskeet/edulinq/blob/master/src/Edulinq/Zip.cs).

Then you can just call:

```
var query = numbers.ZipTuple(letters, words, pictures, songs);
```

I'd probably implement each independently from scratch, but you *could* do it with one call to the "previous" `ZipTuple` and one call to `Zip` in each case, e.g.

```
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<T1, T2, T3>> ZipTuple<T1, T2, T3>(
    this IEnumerable<T1> source1,
    IEnumerable<T2> source2,
    IEnumerable<T3> source3)
{
    return source1
        .ZipTuple(source2)
        .Zip(source3, (t1, extra) => Tuple.Create(t1.Item1, t1.Item2, extra));
}

public static IEnumerable<Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4>> ZipTuple<T1, T2, T3, T4>(
    this IEnumerable<T1> source1,
    IEnumerable<T2> source2,
    IEnumerable<T3> source3,
    IEnumerable<T4> source4)
{
    return source1
        .ZipTuple(source2, source3)
        .Zip(source4, (t1, extra) => Tuple.Create(t1.Item1, t1.Item2, t1.Item3, extra));
}
```

The direct version would look something like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4>> ZipTuple<T1, T2, T3, T4>(
    this IEnumerable<T1> source1,
    IEnumerable<T2> source2,
    IEnumerable<T3> source3,
    IEnumerable<T4> source4)
{
    // TODO: Extract a separate public method from the implementation
    // method and perform eager validation for nullity
    using (var iterator1 = source1.GetEnumerator())
    using (var iterator2 = source2.GetEnumerator())
    using (var iterator3 = source3.GetEnumerator())
    using (var iterator4 = source4.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (iterator1.MoveNext() && iterator2.MoveNext() &&
               iterator3.MoveNext() && iterator4.MoveNext())
        {
            yield return Tuple.Create(
                iterator1.Current,
                iterator2.Current,
                iterator3.Current,
                iterator4.Current);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, you _could_ implement ZipTuple the way you showed, but might give kids bad ideas. Plus, the implementation with a for loop is so brilliantly simple that it's sad not to show off how great the yield syntax is.

Comment: @d--b: Will add an example of that.

Comment: Ah, nice, I thought I'd do it (hence my answer below). Could you expand on the need of the `using` blocks ?

Comment: I mean, why does `IEnumerator<T>` implement `IDisposable`? Is that because of some COM legacy?

Comment: @JonSkeet Please see my updated question. Is it possible to merge all of those list I included?

Comment: @d--b: Aside from anything else, it allows iterator blocks to have `finally` blocks which will be executed appropriately. `foreach` disposes automatically.

Comment: @John.P: As Patrick said, what you were asking for in the update is exactly what I've provided - you'd just need to have as many overloads as you need type arguments.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I am just stupid, but a `for` loop would usually do very good (assuming all lists have the same length):

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Count; i++)
{
    var n = numbers[i];
    var l = letters[i];
    var w = words[i];
    var p = pictures[i];
    var s = songs[i];

    // use your variables

    Console.WriteLine($"number  = {n}");
    Console.WriteLine($"letter  = {l}");
    Console.WriteLine($"word    = {w}");
    Console.WriteLine($"picture = {p}");
    Console.WriteLine($"song    = {s}");
}
```

Comment: This doesn't generally work on IEnumerable, it assumes the inputs are List<>

Comment: Indeed, you could use `Count()` and `ElementAt` as replacements. @d--b

Comment: well no, these would iterate the IEnumerable way too many times. Each `ElementAt` contains its own for loop!

Comment: It will check if the source is a list and use that. Walking the `IEnumerable` yourself is also possible.

Comment: @d--b of course using `Count()` and `ElementAt` on `IEnumerable` is pretty stupid, but author is asking about list, and it's the best way to iterate through multiple lists.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I tried this method, but all that came out was: `System.Collection.Generic.List '1[System String]`

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy: yes sorry I didn't see it was lists

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately in C# you can't define a generic method with as many generic arguments as you want. So you would have to define your Zip function for any number of generic types.

For instance, for 3 generic arguments:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Zip<T1,T2,T3> (this IEnumerable<T1> e1, IEnumerable<T2> e2, IEnumerable<T3> e3) 
{
    var i1 = e1.GetEnumerator();
    var i2 = e2.GetEnumerator();
    var i3 = e3.GetEnumerator();

    // warning: this implementation does not fail if the enumerable do not
    // have the same sizes, it stops when the shortest one is enumerated
    while (i1.MoveNext() && i2.MoveNext() && i3.MoveNext()) {
        yield return Tuple.Create(i1.Current,i2.Current,i3.Current);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please see my updated question. Is it possible to merge all of those list I included?

Comment: @John.P: if you want to loop through a large number of lists, the for loop described by Patrick is really the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a several ways

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Zip<T>(this List<T> source, params IEnumerable<T>[] collections)
    {
        source.AddRange(collections.SelectMany(collection => collection));
        return source;
    }
```

Or:

```
var concat = letters.Concat(numbers).Concat(songs).Concat(pictures);
```

Or:

```
var union = letters.Union(numbers).Union(songs).Union(pictures);
```

Or if you want Tuples, you can do this:

```
letters.Zip(numbers, Tuple.Create).Zip(pictures, (x, y) => Tuple.Create(x.Item1, x.Item2, y)).Zip(songs, Tuple.Create)
```

Or

```
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<T, T>> ZipTuple<T>(this List<Tuple<T, T>> source, IEnumerable<T> collection )
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<T, T>> ZipTuple<T>(this List<Tuple<T, T, T>> source, IEnumerable<T> collection)
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<T, T>> ZipTuple<T>(this List<Tuple<T, T, T, T>> source, IEnumerable<T> collection)
etc...
```